# error 0x801c0002 while joining AAD hybrid domain

Tags: active-directory, azure, entra-id

I am setting up a test lab to simulate an AAD hybrid model. When I try to join  Windows 10 device, I get an error of 0x801c0002.

I can see the device in Azure AD but the status of dsregcmd/join /debug is always in error.

[image]

[dnsregcmd /status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Bnyd.png)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following way to check and solve this:

1. retrieve the join status by using `dsregcmd /status` command in command prompt as an administrator.

The response like this:
[image]

2. Evaluate the join status

**AzureAdJoined**

This field indicates whether the device is joined with Azure AD. If the value is NO, the join to Azure AD has not completed yet.

**DomainJoined**

This field indicates whether the device is joined to an on-premises Active Directory or not. If the value is NO, the device cannot perform a hybrid Azure AD join.

**WorkplaceJoined**

This field indicates whether the device is registered with Azure AD as a personal device (marked as Workplace Joined).

**WamDefaultSet**

These fields indicate whether the user has successfully authenticated to Azure AD when signing in to the device.

For the detail causes to the each field, please read [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/devices/troubleshoot-hybrid-join-windows-current).

Comment: dnsregcmd/status show domain joined but not azureadjoined.